# ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, core.js:15724

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and angular framework. I started a project referring [Auth login](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/)

After following all steps I stuck with error, as this is new framework I am unable to solve.

Code

login.page.ts

```
    import { AuthenticationService } from './../../services/authentication.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

}
```

and login.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-button (click)="login()" expand="block">Login</ion-button>
  <ion-button expand="block" color="secondary" routerLink="/register" routerDirection="forward">Register</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

and I am getting this error when I load page:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:38)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
```

PS: I have 2 files, 
1: login.page.html,

2:  login.module.ts

Comment: create separate ts file for the component

Comment: what you mean by separate files? I have 2 files 1. html and second ts

Comment: separate ts and html file for component

Comment: yes, I have separate files. I shared above both files. Or is there anything wrong with structure, please let me know

Comment: I think its because you don't separate your login modules  and your login components they can't be at the same files.

Comment: @sam, Yes I got this. Can anyone please update me about module and component ts files ?

Comment: I found this , it can help you  : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/confusion-about-angular-ionic-v4-architecture-components-modules-and-pages/139037/2

Comment: Also I am getting another error, please check this also

Comment: Do you have a loop infinite ?

Comment: I didnt see any. Shoud I post app.components.ts file here?

Comment: I don't think its your app component maybe your node modules  is not install properly.

Comment: so How should i solve this ?

Comment: I don't know,  try to see if you have error in your path from your import .

Comment: no eeror shown in visual studio and also run time terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As look like you are calling a function in loop or you may miss import router module in login module, check it again.